# PHP Search through array and add similar values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a MySQL database from which I am retrieving values to my PHP in an array. Here the example of array I am getting in PHP.

[image]

Now I want to sort this array and add similar values against column1. For example, Column1 contain key and column2 contains values. Let's say I have No. 2 in column1 5 times then I want to add values of each of that 5 rows. And same for the rest of the array. If there's a key one more time, I want to add the respective values.

If not PHP, can it be done through MySQL query ?

EDIT:

expected output would be

[image]

Let me explain. 25 is the sum of all values where 0 is in column1 and so on till 9

Comment: Please show us what the expected output would be here, to make your question more clear.

Comment: Next time see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... images are not good to reproduce the problem

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Yes, after seeing the solution, I felt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:
assuming 0 is column1 and 1 is column2

```
$result = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $result[$row[0]] = isset($result[$row[0]]) ? $result[$row[0]] + $row[1] : $row[1];
}
asort($result)
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT column1, sum(column2)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY column1
```

Comment: Can you add some description as to how you think this answers the question.

Comment: Well, It actually worked. He exactly knew what I was expecting, great man. 

And I feeling too noob for such an easy answer.

Comment: well i have added PHP version too, but he asked for php or mysql. and that what i think he was asking for. in a very obscured way he asked about the sum grouped by column1 and have it sorted by column1 too..

Comment: My problem solved on MySQL part. Not even a PHP script needed

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I am referring to the answer I am commenting on. This posted answer solved my problem.

Comment: ok then i simply misread your comment @Mahadev